# Eclipse CDT "New Class" default paths for created source files

Tags: c++, testing, eclipse-cdt

How can I configure Eclipse 4.2 to put the test file in `tests/` when using the New Class wizard?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing... well, I was looking to automate it.  In the remote case you didn't figure out any solution at all, here's my solution that is a 2 extra clicks and some typing (steps 3 and 4).

1. Right click folder you want your new source files (.h and .cpp) to be in, and choose create new class
2. Type the 'class name' as usual, check 'unit test'
3. Click Browse next to unit test and click ok, without selecting a file (but don't hit cancel!).

   - choosing a path doesn't do anything.  It would be nice if Eclipse would append the path to the file name, but it doesn't.
   - What it does do is change the source folder to the project root, and fills in a relative path for the other 2 files, `src/class.h` and `src/class.cpp`.
4. Type `test/` in front of the test file name to specify the path.